# Hateoas - No suitable constructor found for Link(java.lang.String)

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest, spring-hateoas, hateoas

For a REST API, in the controller I'm applying hateoas. When adding the part of Link in the methods, I get the follow error:
`Cannot resolve constructor 'Link(String)'`

In the pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The code is as follows:

```
 @GetMapping
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<List<UserResponseDTO>> get() {

    // Retrieve users
    List<UserResponseDTO> responseDTOS = new ArrayList<>();
    List<User> users = userService.getUsers();

    // Convert to responseDTOS
    for (User user : users) {
        UserResponseDTO userResponseDTO = new UserResponseDTO(user.getId(), user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName());

        Link get = new Link("http://localhost:8081/user/").withRel("GET");

        userResponseDTO.add(get);
        responseDTOS.add(userResponseDTO);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(responseDTOS, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Link(String)` is deprecated and may be removed in some new version. Also `Link(String)` uses the protected access modifier meaning you should access it only from the same package.

You can still create the `Link` using the `of` static method which by the way is defined with public access modifier.

So it should be

```
Link get = Link.of("http://localhost:8081/user/").withRel("GET");
```